# Reading multiple JSON files using Spark 2.4 vs Spark 3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I've to read a bunch of JSON files from Azure data lake. I'm using Databricks, when I use the cluster using Spark 2.4.5 I am able to read the all the files but when I use Spark 3.0.1 the dataframe returned is empty.
I am using the following command,

```py
dfa = spark.read.json("dbfs:/mnt/abc/bronze/xyz/history/*.json", multiLine=True)
dfb = dfa.select(explode("result").alias("result"))
dfc.show(truncate = False)
#this returns 0 records with Spark 3 but returns the data when the notebook is attached to Spark 2.4
```

I tried multiple options like changing the encoding when reading the files but that didn't work.

The file content is very straight forward, the files have content similar to this,

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "number": "abc123",
            "active": "false",
            "cat_item.category": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is getting the schema out of the first record, then apply it to the rest of your data

```py
schema1 = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('result', T.StringType()),
])
                                       

df = spark.read.json("a.json", multiLine=True, schema=schema1)
df.show()
+--------------------+
|              result|
+--------------------+
|[{"number":"abc1..."| <<< string
+--------------------+

schema2 = F.schema_of_json(df.first()['result'])
df = df.withColumn('json', F.from_json('result', schema2))
df.show(10, False)
df.printSchema()
+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|result                                                       |json               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|[{"number":"abc123","active":"false","cat_item.category":""}]|[{false, , abc123}]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+

root
 |-- result: string (nullable = true)
 |-- json: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- active: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cat_item.category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks @pltc but id I have to read multiple files where sometime the columns are of struct types while sometimes are string, defining a schema is an issue. In my case there are files where the category columns is either string or struct type. Let's say if the column is struct type and I define the column in the schema as struct and read the file it doesn't display/show any records but when I use string it does show the data but not as key value data format rather as string.

Comment: I see, it wasn't clear in your original question though, please check my updated answer